# Show that $\left\{0 \right\} \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}$ is totally $d$-disconnected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$\left\{0 \right\} \cup \left\{ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}: n ∈ \mathbb{N} \right\}$$

Prove that X is totally $d$-disconnected, where $d$ is the metric induced by
the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that to be totally $d$-disconnected each component of $X$ must consist of a single point.

Let $x, y\in X$.  Assume that $x\neq y$ are two elements belonging to the same component of $X$.  There is always always a number $z\notin X$ between $x$ and $y$, such that min$\left\{x, y\right\}<z<$max$\left\{x, y\right\}$.  Therefore the sets $(-\infty, z)\cap C_d(x)$ and $(z, \infty)\cap C_d(x)$, where $C_d(x)$ is the connected component containing $x$ and $y$, form a disconnection of $C_d(x)$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore $x \neq y$ is false and $C_d(x)$ consists of a single point and $X$ is totally $d$-disconnected.

I'm partially posting this question just to make sure the logic is sound and partially I'm not sure whether I can justify just saying there exists a point $z$.  I assume I can because it is intuitive that there is at least one point not in $X$ between each point of $X$.

Comment: Yeah, I think your argument is fine. It's not hard to justify the existence of the point $z$: for example, suppose $x = 1/\sqrt{5}$ and $y = 1/\sqrt{2}$. Can we find a $z \notin X$ such that $x < z < y$? Certainly! We can take $z = 0.6$, or $z = 0.67$ or $z = 0.672$... in fact, any number between $1 / \sqrt 5$ and $1 / \sqrt 2$ (other than $1 / \sqrt 3$ or $1 ./ \sqrt 4$) is fine!

Comment: @KennyWong Thanks for your response.  So you think just stating it is ok?  I wasn't sure if I would have to something like the Archimedean principle (if that is appropriate) or something to justify it.

Comment: I suppose we can use the Archimedean principle. In the example I gave, this boils down to checking that $(\tfrac 1 {\sqrt 5}, \tfrac 1 {\sqrt 4}) \cup (\tfrac 1 {\sqrt 4}, \tfrac 1 {\sqrt 3}) \cup (\tfrac 1 {\sqrt 3}, \tfrac 1 {\sqrt 2})$ is non-empty, and this does follow from the Archimedean principle.

Comment: @KennyWong Great!  Foolishly though, I didn't consider when I opened this question that the only way to mark it answered is if someone posted a correction.  Should I just answer my own question then?

Comment: Yeah, go ahead!

Comment: @KennyWong Done!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x, y\in X$.  Assume that $x\neq y$ are two elements belonging to the same component of $X$.  It follows from the Archimedean principle that there is always always a number $z\notin X$ between $x$ and $y$, such that min$\left\{x, y\right\}<z<$max$\left\{x, y\right\}$.  Therefore the sets $(-\infty, z)\cap C_d(x)$ and $(z, \infty)\cap C_d(x)$, where $C_d(x)$ is the connected component containing $x$ and $y$, form a disconnection of $C_d(x)$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore $x \neq y$ is false and $C_d(x)$ consists of a single point and $X$ is totally $d$-disconnected.